# How to get the selected item delegate in a QListView

Tags: qt, delegates, qlistview

I want to implement drag and drop on my QListView, so I would like to get the selected item delegate. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this for myself, but this is what I found out by reading the [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/classes.html).

`QListView` has a `QList<QModelIndex>` which contains the selected items. You can access this list using `QListView::selectedIndexes()`.

Then you can call `QAbstractItemView::itemDelegate( const QModelIndex& index )` for your selected index. This function returns a `QAbstractItemDelegate*`.

- [QListView::selectedIndexes()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qlistview.html#selectedIndexes)
- [QAbstractItemView::itemDelegate( const QModelIndex& index )](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractitemview.html#itemDelegate-2)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help You, but You can use this functions:

```
void QListView::currentChanged ( const QModelIndex & current, const QModelIndex & previous ) [virtual protected]
```

and

```
void QAbstractItemView::dataChanged ( const QModelIndex & topLeft, const QModelIndex & bottomRight ) [virtual protected slot]
```

and refer to [Qt QAbstractItemView class documentation](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html)

greetings
Robert